# SQL Different query results from Oracle Managed Provider vs. SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables, like the following, in Oracle 11g database:

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
    courseID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    courseName VARCHAR(100),
    limit INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE students (
    studentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE attends (
    student INTEGER,
    course INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES students(studentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES courses(courseID),
    CONSTRAINT attends_PK PRIMARY KEY (student, course)
);
```

and try to create a query that lists all the courses which a given student does not currently attend, AND is not full (eg. fewer people attend it than its limit)

I made to following query for this:

```
SELECT c.coursename, c.courseid, c.limit
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN attends a ON a.course = c.courseid
WHERE c.limit > (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM courses cInner 
    INNER JOIN attends aInner ON cInner.courseid = aInner.course
    WHERE cInner.courseid = c.courseid)
AND a.student <> :studentID OR a.student is null;
```

Now, testing this in SQLDeveloper (with substituting :studentID manually) this works flawlesly.
BUT executing this query in the Oracle Managed SQL provider through ADO.Net, the returned rows include cases where the limit condition should be false, even if I manually substitute the same studentID directly in the sql string.

What can cause the problem? or what would be a nicer and safer way of doing this kind of query?

Edit: Tried another query for the same purpose:

```
SELECT limit, coursename, courseID FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(a.course) as attends_count, c.courseID, c.limit, c.coursename FROM courses c
    LEFT JOIN attends a ON a.course = c.courseid
    GROUP BY courseID, c.limit, c.coursename)
WHERE limit > attends_count
AND courseID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT courseID FROM courses
    LEFT JOIN attends ON courseID = attends.course
    WHERE student <> 2 OR student is null
)
```

and the exact same problem is present, a course that is full is also returned by the query when executed from the C# provider, and this alternative query also works in SQLDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

> try to create a query that lists all the courses which a given student does not currently attend, AND is not full (eg. fewer people attend it than its limit)

This sounds like a conditional aggregation and a comparison:

```
SELECT c.coursename, c.courseid, c.limit
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_students,
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.student = :studentID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_student
      FROM attends a
      GROUP BY a.courseId
     ) a
     ON a.course = c.courseid
WHERE a.has_student IS NULL AND
      c.limit > COALESCE(a.num_students, 0)
```